# jQuery modify option html menu to disable

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html-select

I cannot modify the html because I am working in wordpress so I would like to do it with jQuery, I think the code is right but it is not working.

Any idea what could cause the problem?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("select option[value*='promoters']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Regards

Comment: Do you have any jsfiddle or demo link for the problem ?

Comment: Assuming your selector is correct for your HTML structure, and the browser allows you to disable `option` elements, then there's no reason that wouldn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/50ozczy4/ Here is not working either

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/50ozczy4/ is working - you forgot include jQuery (select jQuery version at left corner)

Comment: Oh! Thanks maybe then is a problem with the plugin to insert the jquery in Wordpress